# Get unique value from Mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

My database table name "Square" structure is look like this:

```
ID      Name    URL           Role
1       ab      www.url.com   xy
2       cd      www.url.com   xy 
3       ef      www.url.com   xy 
4       ab      www.url.com   xy
5       cd      www.url.com   xy
6       gh      www.url.com   xy
```

Now, I want to get unique value from this table. For example. Unique name is : ab, cd, ef, gh  with id, url and role.

so my sql query is look like this:

```
$getpara = $_GET['role'];
$getsquare = mysql_query("SELECT ID, DISTINCT (Name), URL, Role FROM Square WHERE Role = 
'$getpara'");
```

but getting error message, may be my sql query is wrong. can you guyes help me plz ?

Comment: You are doing DISTINCT on one value, you need to group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` like

```
$getsquare = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Name, URL, Role 
                          FROM Square 
                          WHERE Role = '$getpara' 
                          GROUP BY Name");
```

And also try to avoid using mysql_* functions due to they are **deprecated**.Instead of them use mysqli_* functions or PDO statements

Comment: Don't piece together SQL strings yourself, you are opening up to SQL injection. Use prepared statements, as seen in http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php .

Comment: I suggested the same in my ans

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT` operates on all the rows,

```
$getsquare = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Name, URL, Role FROM Square WHERE Role = '$getpara' GROUP BY Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$getpara = $_GET['role'];
$getsquare = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID, URL, Role FROM Square WHERE Role = 
'$getpara'");
```

Try this one without the '()' and the DISTINCT first.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `DISTINCT` and your query will work fine - As you have unique names, `DISTINCT` CLAUSE is not required.